# Selected Picklist value not getting assigned to Variable in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a picklist field in flow, but on selecting any value in the picklist, it’s not assigning value to a variable.
How can I get the selected value in a variable?

**Picklist in Flow:**
[image]

**Debug Value in Flow:**
[image]

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.  I removed Apex because your post does not involve Apex.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Kindly check if the choice values have been given for the choices created.